# Azure App Service going to 100% scaling up and I turned everything off and restarted

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I'm not sure what to do here or exactly how to debug this given the steps I've already taken.
1st off I'm running asp.net web apps and azure functions on this Service plan. Very light loads not public facing or anything and I haven't made any changes for days.
Then at 12:30 this afternoon I don't know why it goes to 80-100% scaling up to 10 instances from 1.

So I looked and didn't really see anything. Then I restarted the app service plan, nothing. Then I turned off all by 6 apps 1 by 1 and their slots. Still 100% cpu. (data out is in the 40 mb as well, sorta strange). Then I restarted the service plan again. Still 100%. What can I do?

Comment: When I run into situations like this, I make sure Application Insights is installed and add additional logging to attempt to gather more information.

Comment: I do have it Application Insights in for some items, but I shut everything off and restarted.

Comment: UPDATE, at 3am last night it autoscaled back down to 1 instance, but it's oscillating back and forth between 0 and 90% cpu. I'm going to just create another service plan and move everything to that.

Answer (score 0):

You could check Autoscale setting by clicking on Scale out. If it is enabled, you can disable autoscale. Incase you want to enable autoscale you can Add a rule for same. 
You may refer to link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hsirtl/2017/07/03/autoscaling-azure-web-apps/

Comment: That's not an issue, the issue is that the CPU is 80-100%, I can scale down to 1 instance, or keep 10, doesn't matter all have 80-100% CPU

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new app service plan and moved things to that. My current app service plan was pretty old any way.